# Is there any Hindu god associated with muscle/muscle strength?

Tags: gods, vedic-gods

We all know that god for general medicine is Dhanvantri, but I want to know whether there is any god / deity particularly associated with muscles and muscle powers.

Comment: **Shri Hanuman**. His photo typically is found in several traditional *AkhAda* styled Gymnasiums. See also [Why is Lord Hanuman also referred as "Bajaranga Bali"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21295/1049)

Comment: The very first assurance given by Maharishi Valmiki through Hanuman, to one and all is, "Be Fearless..." Even today that assurance of Hanuman is ruling high on the Hindu psyche and Hanuman is to be remembered in any event of fright !.

Comment: Hinduism believes in self-realization and god-realization and it does not talk about ….muscles or physical body……rather….it talks about Atma and Atma-jnana!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lord Hanuman is associated with muscles and muscle powers/strength.

From **Hanuman Chalisa**:

> बुद्धिहीन तनु जानिके सुमिरौ पवन कुमार ।
>   बल बुद्धि विद्या देहु मोहि हरहु कलेस बिकार् ॥
>
> O Hanuman, O Lord, as I am ignorant and lack of wisdom, I pray to you to take away all my woes and worries and shower on me wisdom, **strength** and knowledge.
>
> रामदूत अतुलित बलधामा ।
>   अञ्जनि पुत्र पवनसुत नामा ॥ 2 ॥
>
> Victory to you, Lord Rama’s messenger, **who embodies strength beyond comparison** and who is also known as Pavanputra and Anjaniputra.
>
> महावीर विक्रम बजरंगी।
>   कुमति निवार सुमति के संगी॥ 3 ॥
>
> You are the great hero, you are endowed with valour, **your body is as strong as Indra's Vajra**. You are the destroyer of vile intellect, and you are the companion of one whose intellect is pure.

---

**Related Post(s)**

[Why is Lord Hanuman also referred as "Bajaranga Bali"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21295/why-is-lord-hanuman-also-referred-as-bajaranga-bali)

Comment: Usually the Avatara-s associated with Vayu represent strength. E.g. Bhima. But yes Shri Hanuman is prime among them. There are many verses explained on "Bajrangi" (strong like Vajra) as well.

Comment: @iammilind ananda teertha